# Pandas, using numpy.where() extracting with regular expression throws ValueError

Tags: pandas, numpy

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here? I am trying to use np.where() like this:

```
#IF SLO contains _ use a regular expression to capture the digit after _Gen, ELSE strip off the last character 
df_joined['new'] = np.where(df_joined['SLO'].str.contains('_'), df_joined['SLO'].str.extract(r'_Gen(\d+)_'), df_joined['SLO'].str.strip().str[-1])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1
```

The data in df_joined['SLO'] is :

```
1997    MIGP8G5
1998    MIGP8G5
1999    MIGP8G5
2000    MIGP8G5
2001    MIGP8G5
2002    MIGP8G5
2003    MIGP8G5
2004    MIGP8G5
2005    MIGP8G5
```

9 rows

When I swap the code to this:

```
np.where(df_joined['SLO'].str.contains('_'), 
         'test', 
         df_joined['SLO'].str.strip().str[-1])
```

It works correctly and 9 elements are returned.

But when I do this:

```
np.where(df_joined['SLO'].str.contains('_'), 
         df_joined['SLO'].str.extract(r'_Gen(\d+)_'), 
         df_joined['SLO'].str.strip().str[-1])
```

81 values are returned

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `expand=False` for avoid one column DataFrame (then numpy want use broadcasting), you need `Series`:

```
print (df_joined)
           SLO
1997  _Gen45_a
1998   MIGP8G5
1999   MIGP8G5

df_joined['new'] = np.where(df_joined['SLO'].str.contains('_'), 
                            df_joined['SLO'].str.extract(r'_Gen(\d+)_'), 
                            df_joined['SLO'].str.strip().str[-1])
```

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1

---

```
df_joined['new'] = np.where(df_joined['SLO'].str.contains('_'), 
                            df_joined['SLO'].str.extract(r'_Gen(\d+)_', expand=False), 
                            df_joined['SLO'].str.strip().str[-1])
print (df_joined)
```

Or select column `0` for `Series`:

```
df_joined['new'] = np.where(df_joined['SLO'].str.contains('_'), 
                            df_joined['SLO'].str.extract(r'_Gen(\d+)_')[0], 
                            df_joined['SLO'].str.strip().str[-1])
print (df_joined)

           SLO new
1997  _Gen45_a  45
1998   MIGP8G5   5
1999   MIGP8G5   5
```

**Details**:

```
print (df_joined['SLO'].str.extract(r'_Gen(\d+)_'))
        0
1997   45
1998  NaN
1999  NaN

print (df_joined['SLO'].str.extract(r'_Gen(\d+)_', expand=False))
1997     45
1998    NaN
1999    NaN
Name: SLO, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great thanks, so it was returning a Dataframe, setting expand=False makes it return a Series.

Comment: @Mick - yop, btw, really awfull problem, I looking for this problem 2 hours once, so always remember it ;)

Comment: glad that you went through the pain, so that I didn't have to. Thanks for your help.